# I want to convert String array to int array to show total

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to make report card of student who is absent in some subject
For example if the student is absent in two subject then the output, should be as:

```
subject    marks
sub1       78
sub2       84
sub3       Absent
sub4       Absent
sub5       34
-------------------
Total:xx   Average:xx



import java.util.*;
public class ReportCard {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter Student name: ");
        String name=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter number of Subject: ");
            int no=sc.nextInt();

        String[] marks =new String[no];
        for(int i=0;i<marks.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter marks of subject"+(i+1)+":");
            marks[i]=sc.nextLine();
        }

        reportCard(marks, name);
        sc.close();

    }
    static void reportCard(String[] marks,String name)
    {
    System.out.print("---------------------------------------\n");
        System.out.print("\t REPORT CARD\n");
        System.out.println("NAME:"+name);
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------\n");
    System.out.println("SUBJECT\t\t       MARKS");
    int total=0;
    for(int i=0;i<marks.length;i++)
        {
         if(marks[i]=="Absent")
            {
              break;
            }
            else
            {
             total=total+marks[i]   
            }

         System.out.println("Subject "+(i+1)+"\t\t"+marks[i]);
        }
     System.out.print("---------------------------------------\n");
     float avg;
     avg=((float)total/marks.length);
     System.out.print("Total: "+total+"\t Average:"+avg);

    }
}
```

String cannot be converted to int

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Integer.parseInt([STRING GOES HERE]) will return an Integer.

Answer (score 0):

`total=total+marks[i]` - This line is taking an int (total) and setting it equal to itself plus `marks[i]`. `marks[i]` is a String because it comes from an array of Strings.

It appears that the only value that `marks` can have that can't be cast to an int is "Absent", so after you check to make sure that the value is not absent you may cast this value to an int so that it can be added to your int total.

Try adding `parseInt()` around `marks[i]`, making the line `total=total+parseInt(marks[i])`.  Be careful to make sure that the values you cast are just String version of ints or you will run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

The string can easily be converted to a valid integer using the java wrapper classes. You can know more about them [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-convert-string-to-int/)!

For example:

```
String number = "10";
int result = Integer.parseInt(number);          
System.out.println(result);
```

Here Integer is the wrapper class. Do note the difference between int and Integer

<--Do UpVote, If Helpful-->
:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the grade to a numeric value.  However, you also need to take care to ensure that the value is actually numeric.

```java
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      String str;
      while (!(str = scan.nextLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("end")) {
         int grade;
         try {
            grade = Integer.parseInt(str);
            System.out.println("numeric grade = " + grade);
         }
         catch (IllegalArgumentException ie) {
            System.out.println("No grade - " + str);
         }
      }
```

When you run the above, you can type in integers or strings.  It will handle them accordingly. If the `parseInt` method tries to convert a word to an `int`, it will throw an `exception`, which is caught and handled appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Trying working with this:

```
import java.util.*;

import com.sun.jndi.url.iiop.iiopURLContext;

import sun.audio.ContinuousAudioDataStream;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter Student Name: ");
        String name=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Number of Subjects: ");
        int no=sc.nextInt();

        sc.nextLine();

        String[] marks =new String[no];
        for(int i=0;i<marks.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter marks for subject "+(i+1)+": ");
            marks[i]=sc.nextLine();
        }

        reportCard(marks, name);
        sc.close();

    }
    static void reportCard(String[] marks,String name)
    {
    System.out.print("---------------------------------------\n");
        System.out.print("\t REPORT CARD\n");
        System.out.println("NAME:"+name);
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------\n");
    System.out.println("SUBJECT\t\t       MARKS");

    int total=0;

    for(int i=0;i<marks.length;i++)
        {
         if(i=="Absent")
            {
              break;
            }
            else
            {
             total = total + Integer.parseInt(marks[i]);  
            }

         System.out.println("Subject "+(i+1)+"\t\t"+marks[i]);
        }
     System.out.print("---------------------------------------\n");
     float avg;
     avg=((float)total/marks.length);
     System.out.print("Total: "+total+"\t Average:"+avg);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*lambda expression separates the calculation of* `total` *from the table printing:*

`…`
`System.out.println( "SUBJECT\t\t       MARKS" );`

```
for( int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++ ) {
  System.out.println( "Subject " + (i + 1) + "\t\t" + marks[i] );
}       
System.out.print( "---------------------------------------\n" );
int total = Stream.of( marks ).filter( m -> ! "Absent".equals( m ) ).collect(
    Collectors.summingInt( Integer::parseInt ) );
```

`float avg = ((float)total / marks.length);`
`System.out.print( "Total: " + total + "\t Average:" + avg );  // Total: 196  Average:39.2`

if `marks[]` contains empty strings, the lambda expression fails with `NumberFormatException` on purpose